# Appending to JSON file efficiently from loop

Tags: node.js, json

i have `json` file like this

```
#json.json

[{"1": 1, "2": 2}]
```

and i have a loop of objects that i wanna append to the file continually (example)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./json.json', 'utf-8'));
    for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        json.push({"1": 1, "2": 2});
    }
    fs.writeFileSync('./json.json', JSON.stringify(json));
}
```

i append every `i` amount of `1000` json object every `j` into the `json.json` file

how can i do it better in efficient way?

do i keep it all in object then append it all at once every `i` (moving `var json` outside completely)?

Comment: Have you considered `appendFile` to add new data to file?

Comment: @HassanImam it give same result as `writeStream.write()` for `fs.createWriteStream()` is it same thing?